# How to add Fragment so that my app don't appear blank on screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm making the Udacity Sunshine app. As there was the version of android studio used was 0.5.8 and now I'm using android studio 3.0.1. thus there are lots of gap between coding techniques used in both of these. 
So, here I used fragment in empty activity and I have implemented it by reading the developer.android.com article on the fragment and I got the abstract idea about it, still much of it not clear.
so I'd done adding fragment and added fake data to List View to populate it.
but when I run that app on my device it still shows a blank screen and none of the text view which I've added in the code:

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

layout/fragment_layout.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArticleFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

layout/list_of_item_forecast.xml

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout"/>
```

package/MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
 }
}
```

package/ArticleFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
    String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

    // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.listview_forecast);
    listview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of app on device]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not instantiating the Fragment class that you have created. You need to instantiate it and pass it to the `FragmentManager`, and also change the `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout)` in your main activity as well.

Just change your `MainActivity.java` class to this and your problem is solved. There is no need to change your layout files.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new ArticleFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and it is now showing the list of items that I'd added. But now the app action bar is missing

Comment: @ShashankeshUpadhyay see updated answer. Extend your activity from AppCompatActivity. As AppCompatActivity already extends from FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues here. Firstly you should have another layout, possibly a `LinearLayout` as the root view in your `activity_main.xml` file, like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_linear_layout_root);

        // Don't leave all this in your onCreate, try refactor
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ArticleFragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
     }
}
```

I haven't seen a framelayout used as the root view and fragment container of an activity, which is why I could be wrong, but this is how I would usually add a fragment to a container.

Comment: There is no need to add a root linear layout. It's not necessary.

Comment: Alright, not sure If I should amend the answer or not.

Answer (score -1):

You should go through this link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/169885/android-fragments-tutorial-introduction-2

Your not setting the content view of your new activity. You may be pushing to StaticFragment Activity, but you don't load the xml of the view. After the super.onCreate() of your yourActivity, add setContentView(R.layout.your_fragment.xml);

**Should fix the issue.**

Comment: He's clearly already done this, please read his code properly